# How can I write file to mpeg movie file to disk in the correct format?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, stream

I'm trying to download an external ts (mpeg) file and write it to disk, but I can't understand how I can get the file content correctly formatted.

I get the file on disk, but it does not play in media player, and when I view attributes of the file it doesn't show any video/sound info like ts files typically do. I've tried many different encodings and I am not even shore if this is the root to the problem or if I need to somehow indicate the contentType, write file attributes or what I am missing here.

Code that writes unplayable file:

```
getFile = (url) => {
  https.get(url, r => {
    let rawData = [];

    r.on("data", chunk => {
      rawData += chunk;
    });

    r.on("end", () => {
      fs.writeFile(`./resources/test.ts`, rawData, "utf-8", err => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(`error writing file`);
          return;
        }

        console.log(`Wrote successfully`);
      });
    });
  });
};
```

This is quite new territory to me. I'm used to serving files and setting content types of all kinds, not downloading them. Would much appreciate help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTF-8 encoding will pad bytes that have the most significant bit set, which corrupts binary files. You can save this to disk without buffering all the data by calling [`res.pipe()`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options) to a [`Writable`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable) stream created by [`fs.createWriteStream()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options):

```
getFile = url =>
  https.get(url, res => {
    res.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./resources/test.ts', 'binary'))
      .on('error', console.error)
      .on('finish', () => { console.log('wrote successfully') })
  })
```

If you want the caller to be able to tell when the download has completed and whether there was an error, you can wrap the return value in a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and use [`stream.finished()`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_finished_stream_options_callback):

```
const { finished } = require('stream')
const getFile = url => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  https.get(url, res => {
    const stream = res.pipe(
      fs.createWriteStream('./resources/test.ts', 'binary')
    )

    finished(stream, err => {
      if (err) reject(err)
      else resolve()
    })
  })
})

// usage
getFile('some url').then(() => {
  console.log('wrote successfully')
}, error => {
  console.error(error)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're requesting binary data, you have to set the encoding accordingly on the response and when calling writeFile. The default encoding is utf-8, which is probably causing the problem here. You could try something like:

```
getFile = (url) => {
    https.get(url, r => {
        let rawData = '';
        r.setEncoding('binary');

        r.on('data', chunk => {
            rawData += chunk;
        });

        r.on('end', () => {
            fs.writeFile(`./resources/test.ts`, rawData, 'binary', err => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(`error writing file`);
                    return;
                }

                console.log(`Wrote successfully`);
            });
        });
    });
}
```